# Remove ZSH/oh-my-zsh history substring search up-arrow functionality

Tags: zsh, history

I recently installed zsh and oh-my-zsh, which come with the history substring search up-arrow functionality that I would like to remove.

Currently pressing the up arrow in my shell having already typed a word will only scroll through my hsitory of commands containing that word.

I would like my up arrow to scroll though my history sequentially, regardless of what I have typed.

What files/settings do I need to change to change this functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to add these two lines to the end of your `~/.zshrc`:

```
bindkey '^[[A' up-line-or-history
bindkey '^[[B' down-line-or-history
```

However, according to [the official documentation](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Customization) the proper way to customize your oh-my-zsh installation is to use `$ZSH_CUSTOM` directory which is usually equal to `~/.oh-my-zsh/custom`.

You can create a file with custom bindings by running these two commands:

```
echo "bindkey '^[[A' up-line-or-history" >> $ZSH_CUSTOM/arrow-keys-bindings.sh
echo "bindkey '^[[B' down-line-or-history" >> $ZSH_CUSTOM/arrow-keys-bindings.sh
```

Here is more information about zsh keybindings: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Zsh#Key_bindings

Comment: I took the lines from `lib/key-bindings.sh` and added them to `custom/key-bindings.sh`, then swapped the keycodes for `up/down arrows` with those for `page-up/page-down.`

Comment: On Mac, the up/down keys are `^[OA` and `^[OB` for some reason.